# Can't solve DNS problem on windows XP machine

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a machine that can't access the server. I tried pinging the using the ip address of the server and it work great. But when I use the name to ping the server it gives a  timeout.

My nslookup cannot resolve the DNS servers but others in my company can. I am wondering is there something that can cause these behavior.

I can access the internet though with their names.

I am runiing on a xp SP2

Answer (score 1):

Are there entries in your hosts file that could be pointing to an incorrect server?  Are your TCP/IP settings correct?  Is TCP/Ip configured with the correct DNS servers in the correct order in the TCP/IP configuration.

Comment: it is dynamically configured. And my setting are the same with others on the networks who can see it. Note though that I had MCAfee Instrusion detection tool on my system some day ago. but I have completely removed it .Could it be an aftermath of the installation

Answer (score 0):

If ping using computer's name says timeout, then it's probably resolved as another ip. Could be bad entry in hosts as Dave M said. Can you use nslookup to ask your DNS server directly for ip adress of that name? What does that say?

Best regards,

Martin Kudlacek

Comment: It say server timeout. Server cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

An easy, low tech way of figuring out what is wrong is comparing the output of "ipconfig /all" on one machine that can resolve it, and yours that can't. Are the DNS servers different?

It is pretty safe to assume you use DHCP to get IP and DNS settings, but perhaps your computer has been manually set up with a static IP and a different set of DNS at some point in time? You can see this under "Internet Protocol v4" under your network adapter properties, where it should say "obtain settings automatically".

Comment: it is dynamically configured. And my setting are the same with others on the network. Note though that I had MCAfee Instrusion detection tool on my system some day ago. but I have completely removed it .Could it be an aftermath of the installation

Comment: With nslookup, did you do a "nslookup host dnsserver" so that you are sure you are asking the servers you think you are? Also, even if you get settings via DHCP, you can get different settings if they are specifically set to something else for your MAC. Are you trying to resolve the name as a FQDN (host.domain) and not just host? If you have a default domain suffix (the .domain part) different from what you think then you might actually be trying to resolve "host.otherdomain". Sometimes suffixes are push via GPOs, and strange things can happen there. :)